# How to break a while loop immediately if the user pressed "q"

Tags: python

I want to get an integer from the user in each loop and add them. If the user presses `q` key I want the loop to end immediately without pressing enter and print the total.

```
!pip install keyboard
import keyboard
total = 0
while True:
  if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    break
  x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  total += x
  print(total)
```

I tried this but I got an assertion error, detailed as follows:

```py
AssertionError                            
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-e1e12bbc6dc8> in <module>()
      3 total = 0
      4 while True:
----> 5   if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
      6     break
      7   x = int(input("Enter a number "))

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixcommon.py in aggregate_devices(type_name)
    166 
    167     # If no keyboards were found we can only use the fake device to send keys.
--> 168     assert fake_device
    169     return fake_device
    170 

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done another way:

```
total = 0

while True:
    x = input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    if x == "q":
        break
    total += int(x)

print(total)
```

Comment: I want it to break immediately, without pressing enter.

Comment: Okay. But you can break it immediately by pressing just Enter if there will be `if x == "": break` statement. No need to press `q`

Comment: Yeah but I want to know if it is possible with other keys.

Comment: Probably you need to elaborate this point in your question. Or you will keep to get incorrect answers otherwise. I see already second answer with the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0
running =True
while running:
    x = input("Bir sayı giriniz: ")

    if x == "q" or x == "Q":
        running = False
    else:
        total += int(x)

print(total)
```

Comment: But you would have to press enter first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without requiring the user to press enter:

```
import sys
import termios
import tty

def getchr():
    r"""
    Get a single key from the terminal without printing it.
    Certain special keys return several "characters", all starting with the
    escape character '\x1b'. You could react to that by reading two more
    characters, but the actual escape key will only make this return a single
    escape character, and since it's blocking, that wouldn't be a good solution
    either.
    """
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
    if ord(ch) == 3:  # ^C
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    return ch


def input_int_except_q(msg):
    print(msg, end="", flush=True)
    chars = []
    while True:
        char = getchr()
        if char == "q":
            return None
        elif char == "\r":
            print()
            break
        print(char, end="", flush=True)
        chars.append(char)
    return int("".join(chars))

total = 0
while True:
    x = input_int_except_q("Bir sayı giriniz: ")
    if not x:
        break
    total += x
    print(total)
```

`getchr` will give you a single character that the user enters, without displaying it. `input_int_except_q` uses that to get an integer that the user entered, or `None` if they pressed <kbd>Q</kbd>. Every character that the user enters is printed back to simulate "normal" line reading, and special care is taken to raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` as usual when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: I get this error: error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Comment: How are you running the script? This will not work if it's not attached to a terminal. It might not work in online python evaluators, "terminals" inside your IDE, etc.

Comment: I am using google collab. Is there really no way to do this without a terminal

Comment: There isn't, outside perhaps Google-Collab/Jupyter-specific hooks that I'm unaware of. For the future: This piece of information ("I'm using collab") was very relevant to the question and should be included in it.

Answer (score 0):

For a Python3 tty, you could use `click`:

```
pip3 install click
```

in a terminal, then:

```
from click import getchar

data = ''
while True:
  char = getchar()
  
  if char == 'q':
    break
  data += char
```